# How to create ("map") complex types through "observables" with Knockout.js?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

So, I'm learning **knockout.js** and I am a bit stumped on how to create nested complex types in it.

For example, on my server-side, my model is:

```
class Person {
public string Name {get; set;}
public int Age {get; set;}
public List<Colors> FavoriteColors {get; set;}
}

class Color {
public int ColorId {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The JSON that asp.net mvc outputs is something like (if I output a `List<Person>` type):

```
[{"Name":"JC","Age":24,"Colors":[{"ColorId":1,"Name":"Red"},{"ColorId":2,"Name":"Blue"}]},
{"Name":"Albert","Age":29,"Colors":{"ColorId":2,"Name":"Blue"}}]
```

Now I want to map that through observables, acquired through Jquery Ajax. I know that `FavoriteColors` would be an array, but I'm a bit confused how things would workout here...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

can anyone help me with this? (i made a prototype, but my select doesn't work)

http://jsbin.com/eqihun/3/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: it looks like there is an unessary array around your data in the sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

edit: your sample edited: http://jsbin.com/eqihun/18/edit

Comment: that seems to "create" the models on the fly only when there is JSON data to parse though.. I need a model that already exists..

Comment: there is var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data); to work with javascript objects

Comment: ..which would bring us back to my question then.

Comment: haha. you're really sticking to your mapping plugin huh. it's a great solution you have there though.. i'm just wondering, what if I want to do "addNewPerson?" I would need a concrete model right?

Comment: @Jan You can using mapping on an existing model that has functions. It's near the end of the documentation. Use `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);` inside your model. You can even map multiple source JSON objects to one model instance. I find it really useful. You can also define your own schema so that array members are mapped to a custom model type in JS.

Comment: @JanCarloViray, to add a new person you just push a new observable User to the Users observableArray

Comment: wow, I am convinced with your mapping plugin evangelism.. that definitely changes things, especially how I won't have to retype the model... thank you :)

Comment: @Guillaume86 you've really helped me on this one, and went out of your way.. i'm making this the 'Answer' :) thanks again!

Comment: @Guillaume86: i have a question.. what if I want the "Colors" to be on a separate array instance (not a JSON)? ie: data = [{..},{..}] ..and then var Colors = [new Color(1, "Blue"), new Color(...)]?

Comment: Well it's kinda the case in my exemple, you can just append the two arrays to the same viewModel. var viewModel = { Users = yourUsersArray, Colors = yourColorArray } and you're done. You only need the Users array to be observable (pass it trough the mapping.fromJS function)

Comment: @Guillaume86 ok, so i'm convinced with the mapping plugin, but I am still having trouble regarding it.. maybe you could help me on my new question about the mapping plugin here? (it's asp.net, but it's about the mapping plugin) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679625/how-can-i-change-asp-net-mvcs-way-of-formatting-json

Comment: @Guillaume86 yeah, thanks I figured that, but I'm having a bit of a trouble like I mentioned from my last comment. If you're able, it would be great if you could help me.. I posted the link to my new question.

Answer (score 2):

link to solution: [here](http://jsbin.com/eqihun/12/edit)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //document.writeln(data[0].Colors[0].Name);

  //if I map anything to ko.observable, it would be sent through ko.toJSON... so that means that Color stuff should NOT be mapped, especially because that's not what MVC is asking, but rather List<Colors>...

  var Color = function (id, name) {
     var self = this;
     self.colorId = id;
     self.name = name;
  };

 function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable("Bert");
    self.Age = ko.observable('12');
    self.FavoriteColors = ko.observableArray([
      new Color(1, "Blue"), 
      new Color(2, "Red"), 
      new Color(3, "White")
    ]);
  } 
  ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());    
});
```

HTML:

```
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/master/build/output/knockout-latest.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" name="Name"></p>
  <p>Age: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Age" name="Name"></p>


  <select data-bind="options: FavoriteColors, optionsText: 'name', value: 'colorId', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Comment: i'm wondering, what's your purpose for adding "type : 'Person'" instead of just naming it "var personModel"?

Comment: it's best practice example in Knockout.js

Comment: ok, mind if you could help me with this one? I tried your sample, but my <select> doesn't seem to work: http://jsbin.com/eqihun/3/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: I have fixed it you can use it.

Comment: You could set it as an answer... no?