# How can I change asp.net mvc's way of formatting JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have this **model**:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Color> Colors { get; set; }
}

public class Color
{
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and asp.net MVC's `return Json(...)` gives me this:

```
[{"Name":"JC","Age":24,"Colors":[{"ColorId":1,"Name":"Red"},{"ColorId":2,"Name":"Blue"}]},
{"Name":"Albert","Age":29,"Colors":[{"ColorId":2,"Name":"Blue"}]}]
```

when I try to return a type of: `List<Person>`

**but I want something like this (if possible):**

```
{"People":[{"Name":"JC","Age":24,"Colors":[{"ColorId":1,"Name":"Red"},{"ColorId":2,"Name":"Blue"}]},{"Name":"Albert","Age":83,"Colors":[{"ColorId":2,"Name":"Blue"}]}]}
```

**MY QUESTION(S):**

- **How can I make C# (asp.net mvc) return JSON with a better format of something like: (note: ignore the data, my main point is for it to return with "People" as the main collection.. how should I do this? JSON.net?)**

  {"People":[{"Name":"JC","Age":24,"Colors":[{"ColorId":1,"Name":"Red"},{"ColorId":2,"Name":"Blue"}]},
  {"Name":"Albert","Age":83,"Colors":[{"ColorId":2,"Name":"Blue"}]}]}
- **OR how can I make *KNOCKOUT.JS MAPPING PLUGIN* work with this type of JSON format? (for those who know knockout)**

  [{"Name":"JC","Age":24,"Colors":[{"ColorId":1,"Name":"Red"},{"ColorId":2,"Name":"Blue"}]},
  {"Name":"Albert","Age":29,"Colors":[{"ColorId":2,"Name":"Blue"}]}]

---

**UPDATE (extra clarification/info):**

this is my data, and I want to return a List

```
    private List<Person> _people = new List<Person>
                                        {
                                            new Person
                                                {
                                                    Name = "JC",
                                                    Age = 24,
                                                    Colors = new List<Color>
                                                                {
                                                                    Red,
                                                                    Blue,
                                                                }
                                                },
                                            new Person
                                                {
                                                    Name = "Albert",
                                                    Age = 29,
                                                    Colors = new List<Color>
                                                                {
                                                                    Blue
                                                                }
                                                }
                                        };
```

in a JSON format similar to this:

```
{"People":[{"Name":"JC","Age":24,"Colors":[{"ColorId":1,"Name":"Red"},{"ColorId":2,"Name":"Blue"}]},
{"Name":"Albert","Age":83,"Colors":[{"ColorId":2,"Name":"Blue"}]}]}
```

i'm just wondering if that is possible, **or if not**, then how can I make the **knockout.js mapping plugin** adapt to MVC's way of returning json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a container since you do not want to return an array but an object with a People variable.

Something like this (using dynamic):

```
var jsonData = new 
            {
                People = _people 
            };
return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**Update**

JSON is really simple format. Let's skip everything that you don't need to now.

- Objects: Objects in json start and end with `{}`. Anything in them corresponds to properties in C#.
- Arrays: Returning a `IEnumerable` will return an array. An array can contain other arrays, objects or simple fields.

The code above is using a dynamic object in C# and can be translated into a class looking like this:

```
public class MyCustomClass
{
    public IEnumerable<Person> People {get;set;}
}
```

Hence it's an object returning an array resulting in:

```
{ People: [] }
```

Where the `{}` corresponds to `MyCustomClass`.

Comment: wow. I've spent hours trying to figure this out.. solved by a small piece of code from one smart guy. thanks a lot. Mind if you could tell me more information/explanation of what you did there? maybe a link to some resources, keywords, or you could tell me? I'm fairly new to C# and JSON..

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials is good. There are some JSON and other fancy things there.

Answer (score 1):

you can return things, in for example, this way:

```
 var jsonData = new
            {
                Name = qry.Name,
                Age = qry.Age,
                Colors = (
                    from c in qry
                    select new
                    {
                        ColorID = c.ColorID,
                        Name = c.Name
                    }).ToArray()
            };

return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Maybe something like that :)

Comment: mind if you could translate that to my models? i'm a bit confused with that and how it would change my json format. thanks

Comment: Did some blindfolded coding, you might need to change things in order for it to work as expected :) and ofc get data and put it in "var qry = .. "

Comment: i'm just a beginner at c# and json but I don't think your code returns a type of List<Person> (?) ...I updated my question for some sample C# data. maybe that may add some clarification. thanks again for your help.